# CakePHP: replace input field with another form element (such as lablel) based on user role

Tags: php, cakephp, view, formhelper

I have 2 models:

1. Books
2. Users

And i have below rules:

1. normal users can create/edit books of themselves only
2. admin users can create/edit books for everyone

I created models of Users and Books and define belong to/one to many realtion
I used cake bake to create CRUD views and controllers. My edit controller action for Books is like this:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Book->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid book'));
        }
        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if ($this->Book->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Book.' . $this->Book->primaryKey => $id));
            $book = $this->Book->find('first', $options);
            if ($this->isUserCanAccessThisRecordActionEdit($book['BookUser']))
                $this->request->data = $book;
            else
                $this->redirectNotAuthorized();
        }
        $bookUsers = $this->Book->BookUser->find('list');
        $this->set(compact('bookUsers'));
    }
```

when edit.ctp displayed, it displays users as a dropdown like this:
[image]
Problem: upon rules I defined i don't want allow normal user to choose book_user_id and only admins are allowed to have such list, I want normal user can view their names as BookUser in other format of controls such as labels. I have tried to access request data to display user name directly but I could not do that (I have no problem to differentiate between user and admins in my views, but i don't know how to change UI and access related data to display information)

**Another bad news:** this way all user name/id pairs are passed to view, so a normal user can have them, which is a bad security idea, e.g. here is the option for Users inside my rendered HTML page of edit.ctp:

```
     <div class="input select required"><label for="BookBookUserId">Book User</label>
<select name="data[Book][book_user_id]" disabled="disabled" id="BookBookUserId">
<option value="3">vhb</option>
<option value="5">vhb2</option>
<option value="6">vhb3</option>
<option value="7">vhb4</option>
<option value="8">vhb5</option>
<option value="9">vhb6</option>
<option value="10">vhb7</option>
<option value="11">vhb8</option>
<option value="12">vhb9</option>
<option value="13">vhb10</option>
<option value="14">vhb11</option>
<option value="15">vhb12</option>
<option value="16">vhb13</option>
<option value="17">vhb14</option>
<option value="18">vhb15</option>
<option value="19">vhb16</option>
<option value="20">vhb17</option>
<option value="21">root</option>
<option value="22">vhb19</option>
<option value="23">vhb20</option>
<option value="24">vhb21</option>
<option value="25">vhb1</option>
</select></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use *distinct models for administrators and users*. It is easy to work and maintain.

I also suggest to *keep your user level checks in AppController*.

For your currently code:

Supposing you are using a field named "is_admin" to check if the user is admin or not:

**In your controller:**

```
public function edit($id = null) {
        if (!$this->Book->exists($id)) {
            throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid book'));
        }

        $isAdmin = ($this->Auth->user('is_admin') == true) ? true : false;
        $this->set(compact('isAdmin'));

        if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {

            if ($isAdmin != true) {

                $this->request->data['Book']['book_user_id'] = $this->Auth->user('id');

            }

            if ($this->Book->save($this->request->data)) {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book has been saved.'));
                return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
            } else {
                $this->Session->setFlash(__('The book could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
            }
        } else {
            $options = array('conditions' => array('Book.' . $this->Book->primaryKey => $id));
            $book = $this->Book->find('first', $options);
            if ($this->isUserCanAccessThisRecordActionEdit($book['BookUser']))
                $this->request->data = $book;
            else
                $this->redirectNotAuthorized();
        }

        if ($isAdmin == true) {

            $bookUsers = $this->Book->BookUser->find('list');
            $this->set(compact('bookUsers'));

        }

    }
```

With this you avoid to load unecessary data.

**In your view:**

```
if ($isAdmin == true) {

    $this->Html->input('book_user_id');

} else {

    echo AuthComponent::user('name');

}
```

Comment: Since I had no encounter with mvc before this it is a bit complex for me to have good understanding  of that

Comment: In the begining of MVC use it`s normal.
You may use prefixes to manage your access or even ACL.
You can find more information about this terms in http://book.cakephp.org/